# Wicket Ajax issue when page is not serialized

Tags: java, ajax, serialization, wicket

Our application uses wicket 1.5.2 and we have built quite a few pages with ajax so far, which makes the pages stateful. We were noticing NotSerializableException [NSE] in the logs but have ignored it since it didn't really break any functionality. Now we started noticing ajax issues in multiple tab/window scenario.

Lets say I have page A which has some ajax behaviors and page B. I loaded page A, right click on a link and opened page B in a new tab. Now when I click on an ajax link in page A, it tries to re-paint the same page [A]. When trying to debug, I noticed it is trying to lookup the page based on page id and since the same won't be present in page store [remember there was NSE due to which the page is not stored] it creates fresh instance of the page and repaints the same.

I know the right thing to do is to allow serialization to be successful but that is going to take some time for us since we have to revisit all the implemented components to ensure we fix those issues. Is there any other quick and (somewhat) nice solution to this?

The other option is to make the page stateless using stateless ajax components [Jolira?] - I don't know how that is going to fair, but will try out. Meantime, if anyone has worked around this problem, pls let me know.

Answer (score 0):

It may sound harsh, but you really should get your code fixed. It is generally a bad idea to ignore exceptions.

Wicket relies on pages being fully serializable to support statefulness. If the serialization of the page fails, there's no guarantee any of Wicket's feature regarding state will work. This is especially true for those parts of a page (i.e. components and models) which you want to update via AJAX.